# Attach DOM elements to other DOM elements only after they have loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom, promise

I am trying to write the code to do the following:

1. When the user uploads the images, return previews of those images as canvas elements. (This is taken care of by loadImage API)
2. Attach div elements next to each of those canvases.

To do the above in order, I will need to invoke document.querySelectorAll method only after the canvas elements are fully drawn.

Here is the code I wrote. I tried to use promise here, but apparently the promise is resolved after the loadImage functions are invoked, not after the canvas elements are fully drawn. When I run the function, the previews are populated as canvas elements, but the 'photo_order' div elements are not attached.

```
function rpu() {
  let promise = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    let filez = e.target.files;
    let files = Array.from(filez);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      loadImage(
        file,
        function(img) {
          document.querySelector('#r_im_preview').appendChild(img);
          document.querySelector('#r_im_preview').classList.remove('hide');
        }, {
          maxWidth: 150,
          orientation: true,
          contain: true
        }
      )
    });
    resolve();
  });
  promise.then(function() {
    let k1 = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    let k2 = Array.from(k1);
    let k3 = '<div class="photo_order" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>'
    k2.forEach(k => {
      k.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', k3);
    })
  });
}
```

How do I fix the code to achieve what I am trying to do? Any advice will be very much welcome.

Comment: As far as I can tell the main problem is that the Promise will resolve immediately after the for loop and not wait for the images to be loaded. Try this: https://pastebin.com/p8vLtVNK

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, @Chris G !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to refactor your code to correctly use promises. Something like this:

```js
const appendPreview = (img) => {
    document.querySelector('#r_im_preview').appendChild(img)
    document.querySelector('#r_im_preview').classList.remove('hide');
}

const loadImageP = (file, cb, settings) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const cbP = (...args) => (cb(...args), resolve)
        loadImage(file, cbP, settings)
    } catch {
        reject()
    }
})

const settings = {
    maxWidth: 150
    orientation: true,
    contain: true
}

async function rpu() {
    const promises = [...e.target.files].reduce((acc, file) => 
        [...acc, loadImageP(file, appendPreview, settings))], [])

    await Promise.all(promises)

    let canvasNodes = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
    let orderNode = '<div class="photo_order" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>'
    [...canvasNodes].forEach((n) => { n.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', orderNode);
}
```